# Add Element to DOM, change styles and apply JS library

Tags: javascript, dom, canvas

I have a page with any number of images with the class `pinch-zoom-element` I want to replace all of that images with canvas and apply them the PinchZoomCanvas [library](https://github.com/vash15/pinch-zoom-canvas). Canvas is added to the code, even the library is applied, but the canvas remains at 0px width and height.

```
var pictures = document.getElementsByClassName('pinch-zoom-element');
for(var i = 0; i < pictures.length; i++){
    var imageItem = pictures.item(i);
    var canv = document.createElement('canvas');
    var foto = imageItem.src;
    canv.id = 'canvasIdItem';
    canv.style.width = "300px";
    canv.style.height = "300px";
    imageItem.parentNode.insertBefore(canv, imageItem.nextSibling);
    imageItem.parentNode.removeChild(imageItem);
    console.log(canv);
    var pinchZoom = new PinchZoomCanvas({
        canvas: canv,
        path: foto,
        zoomMax: 2,
        doubletap: true,
        onZoomEnd: function (zoom, zoomed) {
            console.log("---> is zoomed: %s", zoomed);
            console.log("---> zoom end at %s", zoom);
        },
        onZoom: function (zoom) {
            console.log("---> zoom is %s", zoom);
        }
    });
}
```

How can I get this working? Thanks in advance!

Comment: try `canv.style.width = "300"`; and so on .

Comment: Same result `<canvas id="canvasIdItem1505407885137" width="0" height="0" style="width: 0px; height: 0px;"></canvas>`

Answer (score 0):

Set your canvas height and width like:

```
canv.style.width = "300";
canv.style.height = "300";
```

You can also set it in your css using specific selector:

```
canvas {
   width: 500px;
   height: 400px;
}
```

Comment: Got same result: `<canvas id="canvasIdItem1505407885137" width="0" height="0" style="width: 0px; height: 0px;"></canvas>`

Comment: remove the internal styles as well.

Comment: That was the result pasted after inspecting the DOM on chrome. I have no internal styles. The issue is on the insertBefore, if I change `imageItem.parentNode.insertBefore(canv, imageItem.nextSibling);` for `document.body.insertBefore(canv, imageItem.nextSibling);`, it works, but the location of the new canvas is just last on the DOM. My goal is to substitute the image for the canvas.